# How do I implement my Java server?

Tags: java

I really don't know what I'm doing, and have been trying to learn about it, but I figured I would ask for help; I have a java server (essentially the one here: http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/OOP_f02/Book/chap09/BroadcastEchoServer.java, just playing around with stuff so I can learn about it), and I want to be able to run it on the internet , so with the client applet I wrote that you can embed in a browser, say, you can connect to it from different computers.  I really have no idea how to go about it.  I downloaded some things (Tomcat, Glassfish), signed up for google app engine, and something I think is similar specifically for Java, but I'm not really sure what I am doing.  I am thinking I get j2ee or something?  I use a mac and xcode, if that's useful at all.

Thanks in advance

Oh, the client applet is like the one from a java socket tutorial here: 
java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: to be honest, your question is quite broad, not to mention a bit incomprehensible. There is a whole stack of technology or something or other that you need to be familiar with before starting on a socket project app kind of thing or kind of uses glassfish, j2ee, tomcat or something, maybe runinng on mac or what. The first step is to get it runing on your local machine. It looks like a standalone server, so you don't need tomcat or j2ee. You will need a host that allows you to run a daemon or service to run the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is already working locally, what you need to do is to put it in a hosting service.

That way it can be accessible by everyone else.

That server, is an stand alone application ( that is, it doesn't need  tomcat or glassfish, and certainly won't run on Google App Engine )

The only thing you need to do, is have it install it in a machine which is accessible from the internet.  How to host an application is out of the scope of this site though.

Comment: what kind of hosting service would allow me to install it?  I can get it working locally.  Is there a way I could run it locally and have it accessible to people on the internet>?

Comment: If your computer is accessible from the internet ( try some one pinging at your ip address )  then,you're done.  The problem is that you need a domain name ( something like mike.ownserver.com ) otherwise people would have to learn you ip address each time. 

You may try Amazon Elastic Compute Close service: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/